# While loop inside of a For loop, jump back into For loop at counter index Python

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

I am parsing through data in a for loop. When the item is found, it kicks to a while loop and finds an item related to it. Within this while loop, I have a counter for the iterations within the while loop. When I kick back to the For loop, it wants to iterate from the original position of the For loop. I am trying to skip those iterations and start equal to the counter.

I am new to SO. If I was not clear enough, I would be happy to answer any questions.

```
for x in range(0, 10):
    if b has been found
         x = counter    
    #find a
        #flag is true

    while flag true:
         #find b
           #flag is false
         #count iterations
```

Comment: can you provide your actual code?
There's no way the outer loop can get controlled by an inner loop, unless of course your inner while loop is resetting the value of `x`

Comment: inside for loop you cannot update the variable x. Just modify it to while loop

Comment: It is currently unclear what you are asking. If that continues to be the case, soon your question will be put on hold (I ain't doing it). I would therefore suggest you to be more clear

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's a bit unclear what exactly you're trying to do with these loops, could you please clarify? Also... This looks like it may be an "XY problem". Please take a look at [What is the XY problem?](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and see if you might be better served by asking your question differently and/or asking a different question. Another good reference for improving question quality is the [ask] page. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you be willing to restructure your code? I think the outer for loop would work better as a while loop:

```
x = 0
while x < 10:
    if b has been found
         x = counter    
    #find a
        #flag is true

    while flag true:
         #find b
           #flag is false
         #count iterations
    x += 1
```

That way, you can change the value of x in the loop.